# No data collected when profiling .NET class library with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, profiling

I'm trying to performance profile the [C5 Generic Collection Library for C# and CLI](https://github.com/sestoft/C5) with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. Since the project has no executable I've made a new Console Application project in the solution. The project contains a simple class with a main method creating one of the data structures with a large collection of elements. The problem is that my CPU sampling always returns with the following output:

```
Profiling started.
Profiling process ID 2684 (C5.Performance).
Process ID 2684 has exited.
Data written to C:\<some path>\C5\C5.Performance130904.vsp.
Profiling finished.
PRF0025: No data was collected.
Profiling complete.
```

and a confirm box that says **PRF0025: No data was collected.** I've tried to changed the collection size so the CPU would have more to do, but without any luck. I have no problem doing .NET memory allocation profiling.

I run Windows 7 on a VirtualBox on a OSX host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable [`Collect .NET object allocation information`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264934.aspx) under the property pages:

1. In **Performance Explorer**, right-click the performance session, and then click **Properties**.
2. On the *Performance Session* **Property Pages** dialog box, click the **General** tab, and select the **Collect .NET object allocation information** check box.
3. To collect .NET object lifetime data, select the **Also collect .NET object lifetime information** check box.

Answer (score 5):

I am coming across the same issue. The common factor is VirtualBox.

CPU sampling does not always work in VirtualBox. It is to do with a bug in VirtualBox where it does not properly implement a hardware clock. I suspect the problem could be hardware specific, it may work under some machines but not others. I know for certain that it doesn't work under my hardware configuration.

See the links below for more details:

[A VirtualBox bug ticket detailing the problem](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12495)

[A ServerFault Question with detailed answers on the problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/194585/visual-studio-profiler-in-virtual-machine)

I do not have a solution to the problem but it is definitely a problem that exists in VirtualBox.