# Memory profiling on Visual studio 2012 PRF0025 error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, profiling

I implemented big program to find nearest neighbor using kd-Tree. But when I test it, used memory is bigger and bigger. I tried this advice, bud still not working. ([No data collected when profiling .NET class library with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609696/no-data-collected-when-profiling-net-class-library-with-visual-studio-2012))

output of profiler:

```
Profiling started.
Warning VSP2355: Some Windows counters will not be collected.  Without this data, some performance rules may not fire.
Profiling process ID 10112 (KdTreeNN).
Process ID 10112 has exited.
Data written to C:\<path>\KdTreeNN\KdTreeNN140529.vsp.
Profiling finished.
PRF0025: No data was collected.
Profiling complete.
```

Some other advices? Please help. Thanks